How to enhance server-side form validation in C# for updating forms?
I have implemented basic server-side validation in the Update action in Teacher Controller to check for empty or null values for certain fields such as TeacherFname, TeacherLname, EmployeeNumber, HireDate, and Salary.
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Update(int id, string TeacherFname, string TeacherLname, string EmployeeNumber, DateTime? HireDate, decimal? Salary)
 {
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(TeacherFname) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(TeacherLname) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(EmployeeNumber) || HireDate == null || Salary == null)
     {
         ViewBag.Error = "All fields are required.";
         return View("Update");

     }

     Teacher UpdatedTeacher = new Teacher();
     UpdatedTeacher.teacherfname = TeacherFname;
     UpdatedTeacher.teacherlname = TeacherLname;
     UpdatedTeacher.employeenum = EmployeeNumber;
     UpdatedTeacher.hiredate = (DateTime)HireDate;
     UpdatedTeacher.salary = Salary ?? 0;

     TeacherDataController controller = new TeacherDataController();
     controller.UpdateTeacher(id, UpdatedTeacher);

     return RedirectToAction("Show/" + id);

 }


I have add a if statement but it's not working for Hiredate and Salary. I want that if a user update the form server should check whether the fields are empty or not.

You can use the HasValue property of a nullable object. In your case the nullable objects are HireDate and Salary, so you can change your condition to:
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(TeacherFname) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(TeacherLname) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(EmployeeNumber) || !HireDate.HasValue || !Salary.HasValue)
{
    ViewBag.Error = "All fields are required.";
    return View("Update");
}

In the above condition, the HasValue property returns a bool value based on the condition if the Nullable variable have some value or not. If the variable has some value, then it will return true; otherwise, it will return false if it doesn't have value or it's null.
You can read more on HasValue
